# media queries for iPad

Tags: ipad, css, media-queries

I have been testing media queries on Browserstack, I need to make specific changes to the page layout for iPads. I can get media queries to work on the desktop version of the site but I can not get media queries to work for all iPads. The following media queries work but only on the latest iPad version which Browserstack refers to as iPad 3rd(7). i have been referencing this site for media queries.
http://code-tricks.com/css-media-queries-for-common-devices/

This first one is the only one I have had success with, but only for iPad3, nothing else works for other iPad versions.

```
 @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px)
    and (orientation : portrait)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
       h1.iPadThis {color:black;}          
    }
```

This should work for all ipad versions but only works for iPad 3

```
  @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
       h1.iPadThis {color:orange;} 
   }
```

I have tried the following for iPad 1 and 2 but it does not work on Browserstack.

```
  @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width : 768px) 
      and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
      and (orientation : portrait) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1){
         h1.iPadThis {color:orange;}              
     }
```

And I have this in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width,height=device-height">
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you also try this :

```
@media (min-width:600px) and (max-width:767px) {


h1.iPadThis {color:orange;}  

}
```

### **or**

```
@media (max-width:767px) {


    h1.iPadThis {color:orange;}  

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but neither worked. Doesn't iPad max-width need to be 768px for portrait though? For clarity, I need to be able to adjust the space above the main titles on this page on iPads which is why I need to target iPad specifically. http://waitakeries.businesscatalyst.com

Comment: For anybody else experiencing the same, I've ended up by using the following to direct iPad/tablets to a separate style sheet <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="css/landscapePortrait.css" />  So far it appears to be working although I am convinced BrowserStack is giving me irregular updates. B-Stack updates the test with whatever change I make in either width, ie, I set a colour in width 1024 and expect 'not' to see it appear in 768, but it does. Seems wrong to me, or I just don't understand B-Stack.